# How do I define a function in python to choose a list.

Tags: python

I am trying to define a function to choose a list. I am writing a text adventure. I chose to represent the rooms as lists, with descriptions, monsters and so on.
Now I want to define a function get_room(id) to bring me the right room

```
Room1=[description1,monster1]  
Room2=[description2,monster2]
```

I guess I could try to make a list of the lists and pick out the right room from that. But wouldn't that be slower?
I am new to programming so I would prefer if the solution doesn't involve classes if at all possible. I am using python 2.7.2.

Comment: How do you define which room is the right room?

Comment: They were meant to be integrers from the beginning. So if I called get_room(1) I would get Room1. I hope that answers both questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your room id is an integer you should use a list.

```
rooms = [Room1, Room2]

# I assume you want to assign your rooms a number from 1 to ...
def get_room(id):
    return rooms[id - 1]
```

If your room is is not an integer but, for example, a string you should use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
rooms = {
    "room1": Room1,
    "room2": Room2
}

def get_room(id):
   return rooms[id]
```

In both cases, whenever you are using dictionary or list you should assume that access to the element is very fast. It is constant time which means that whenever dictionary/list has 10, 100, or 100000 elements selecting element from them will take the same amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `dictionary` like this:

```
dict = {
        'Room1' : ['description1','monster1'],
        'Room2' : ['description2','monster2']
       }
```

And than call them like:

```
print dict['Room1']
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you may declare your rooms in a unique variable:

```
valid_rooms = [['description1', 'monster1'],
['description2', 'monster2']]
```

So that it becomes easier for manipulating them.
Example for getting the user required position room:

```
var = raw_input("Please enter room number: ")
print("you entered"), var
selectedRoom = int(var)
print( "room index %d : %s" % (selectedRoom, valid_rooms[selectedRoom]))
```

**Important**: I strongly recommend you to test the int conversion of user input:

```
try:
    myint = int(var)
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry you do not enter a valid INTEGER!")
```

*Remark*: in the proposed scenario the function get_room() would be very simple (maybe not so useful)

```
def get_room(id):
  return valid_rooms[id]
```

*Note* that in python 3.x `raw_input` was rename `input`.